# Fresh SpeakHere example app has error when recording audio in Simulator/Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, audio-recording

I can't record audio using the [SpeakHere](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html) example app from apple. When I run the app in Simulator from within Xcode, it starts up normally, but when I press the record button, the error "Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)" occurs:[image: screenshot after problem occurred]

The log message about the missing root view controller at app startup is already there BEFORE the above error occurs and it is probably not connected to my problem.

I have downloaded the SpeakHere example project from the linked website (see top of this question), opened the fresh download in Xcode and directly started the app. I did not modify any setting and not any line of code. I've also searched on google and stackoverflow for this problem and didn't find a solution, although this problem must be very general.

I use Xcode Version 4.5.2 (4G2008a) and a MacBook Pro from late 2009 with Mac OS X 10.8.

I've also had a friend try this on his computer and he has the very same problem. He has the same OS and his XCode version is also 4.5.2.

I would now try older Xcode versions, but right now I don't like to download a few gigabytes for a trial'n'error approach on my connection.

Any help appreciated, including reports like "works for me with Xcode version ...". Thanks!

Comment: I've tried iOS-Simulator in versions 6.0 and 5.1. In both versions, the same problem occurs.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem occurs because in the method `AQRecorder::StartRecord(CFStringRef inRecordFile)`, the function `CFURLCreateWithString()` fails and returns a pointer to nil. This is not detected and later on the code calls `CFRelease()` on this nil pointer, which causes the EXC_BREAKPOINT.

The purpose of the method `CFURLCreateWithString()` basically is to take a url string as input and return a pointer to a CFURL object as output. The problem here is that the input is not a url string. Instead, it's simply a path on the local file system without `file:/` or the like as prefix. For this reason, this method fails.

The solution is to remove the not-working call to the method `CFURLCreateWithString()` and instead call a related method, namely `CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath()`, which is prepared to take a local file system path and convert it to a CFURL:

In the method `AQRecorder::StartRecord(CFStringRef inRecordFile)`, replace or comment out the line

```
url = CFURLCreateWithString(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)recordFile, NULL);
```

and insert

```
url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)recordFile, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, false);
```

at its place.

Comment: This applies to SpeakHere Version 2.5, 2012-09-10.

Answer (score 0):

```
url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)recordFile, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, false);
```

The code above made my xcoce 4.6 compile and run in simulator, but it doesnot record my voice from my usb microphone, I test my microphone in the garash band application and sucessfully record and play my voice, and the dbmeter does not move at all, any way when I port it to the real device it work, it just can't record and play voice in my simulator.

Comment: Hi Johnson, the problem you found is an important topic. To get enough attention to it, it is important to post it as a separate question on stackoverflow. So far, you posted it here as an answer to an already answered question. This way, it will not be seen by the people who might be able to solve your question.

Comment: @DanielS. that is the best ever comment I've ever seen helping a new person at SO. Bravo.