# iPhone:Recording audio with custom volume indicator

Tags: iphone, volume, indicator

I am developing an app in which I need to record the audio.

Now while recording the audio I need to show the custom volume indicator like, speedometer which will show the volume level  of the recoding audio.

So please help me if any one has an idea about how to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this audio meter.. is not analog.. but.. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html

if you want analog.. you must combine Apple exemple with this  analog [speedometer](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/ios-tutorial-custom-speedometer-control/) .

~same answer here [objective c audio meter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170002/objective-c-audio-meter).. or... [AVAudioRecorder meter delay on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646272/avaudiorecorder-meter-delay-on-ipad?rq=1)

Comment: if SpeakHere example app has error when recording - you can check this   http://stackoverflow.com/a/13630557/1702413

Comment: [This](https://github.com/mike-dutka/gl-data-visualization-view) framework also contains implemented pretty nice volume indicator (VU Meter).