# SpeakHere sampe from Apple Can't record voice in Xcode 6.1 simulator but can record voice in 5.1, work in real device

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, simulator

I can't record audio using the SpeakHere example app from apple. When I run the app in Simulator version 6.1 from within Xcode, it starts up normally,but when I touch the record button, the level meter does not move at all, and the audio file just don't have voice inside,
yes the audio file is existed. The strange thing is when I change the Simulator to version 5.1
, it look like the recording is working, the level meter is working, but when I push the play button, there is no sound at all but the meter is moving, I check the audio file by playing from third party application, it is OK, so version 5.1 simulator, it can record and can't play, but with output error message like: 
Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable

**Summary:**
   My machine is Mini Mac, OSX 10.8.2 with USB headset with mic.

- in version 6.1 simulator, it can't report and can't play.
- in version 5.1 simulator, it can report and can't play.

Can anyone has any idea how to fix all this to be work in simulator?
I push the SpeakHere sample application and it work in 6.1 real device ( my iPad).

Comment: I think you cannot run that in Simulator?  You have to run that on a device.

Comment: I think that Link should help:
 


: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13627193/fresh-speakhere-example-app-has-error-when-recording-audio-in-simulator-xcode